# How to prove that $ab | \lceil \frac{n}{4} \rceil +c$?

Tags: divisibility

Prove that for all positive integers $n \geq 17$ such that $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \right\rfloor \equiv 0 \pmod 2$, there exists positive integers $a, b$ and an even positive integers $c$ such that the following are satisfied:

$$ a+b = 4c-1$$ and 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor + c \equiv 0 \pmod {ab}$$

To me, this seems logical but I've spent the past month trying to prove it but haven't been able to make any progress. I feel really stumped. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How does that seem "logical"? And what is the purpose behind the $\lceil n/4\rceil$ when that expression just runs over all positive integers as well?

Comment: This is just a lemma for a larger problem that I am proving so that's where the $\lceil n/4 \rceil$ is from and thank you for your edits, I am still learning LaTex.

Comment: Might help to note that $\left\lceil\frac{n}{4}\right\rceil\equiv0\pmod2 \iff n\equiv0,5,6,7\pmod8$.

Comment: After your last edits, it seems you could still start with "for all even integers $m\ge 4$ ..." and replace $\lfloor n/4\rfloor $ with $m$

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ as in the problem statement let $c:=\lfloor \frac n4\rfloor$, $a=2c$, $b=2c-1$.

Comment: 2c= 0 (mod 2c*(2c -1))???